# ¿Es igual utilizar .AsString que .Text para obtener el valor de un campo de un DataSet?

Tags: delphi

Luego de ver cierto código, me he dado cuenta que utilizan este estilo:

```
aStr:=tblAcct.FieldByName('Name').Text;
```

Parece trabajar bien, pero yo había utilizado hasta ahora:

```
aStr:=tblAcct.FieldByName('Name').AsString;
```

He utilizado ambos al cargar un TMemo y no parece haber diferencia alguna.

```
aMemo.Lines.Text:=tblAcct.FieldByName('History').Text;
aMemo.Lines.Text:=tblAcct.FieldByName('History').AsString;
```

¿Hay alguna razón por la que deba utilizar una y no la otra? ¿Cuál es esa razón?

Normalmente, para un memo, utilizo:

```
aMemo.Lines.Assign(tblAcct.FieldByName('History'))
```

Y esto trabaja bien también.

Comment: Ante dos alternativas iguales para hacer lo mismo, utiliza siempre la más legible.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Antes de responder directamente la respuesta, hablaremos de las propiedades relevantes de TField y sus descendientes.

## `Text`/`DisplayText`

Ambas propiedades sirven para obtener una representación textual del valor del campo para su uso en la Interfaz de Usuario. 
El propósito de la propiedad `Text` es el de obtener una representación textual del campo cuándo está siendo editado en un control asociado a datos (Data Aware), en contraste con la propiedad `DisplayText` que proporciona el valor del campo con formato de visualización para el usuario, por ejemplo, puede contener caracteres de puntuación u otra decoración al valor plano. (1234.50 en contraste con 1,234.50).

En otras palabras, un `TdbEdit` o controles similares, mostrarán el valor de `DisplayText` cuándo no están siendo editados, y al recibir el foco, cambiarán el valor al de la propiedad `Text` y es este valor el que el usuario "edita". Un TdbLabel solamente tira de la propiedad `DisplayText`, ya que no es editable.

La documentación para `Text` dice:

> Contains the string to display in a data-aware control when the field is in edit mode

Un ejemplo típico es un `TFloatField` con la propiedad `Currency` establecida a `True`. La propiedad DisplayText te devuelve el string con el número conteniendo separadores de miles, el separador decimal y el símbolo de la moneda. La propiedad Text, te devuelve una cadena que no contiene separadores de miles ni símbolo de moneda.

```
begin
  MyFloatField.Currency := True;
  MyFloatField.AsFloat := 1234.56;
  A := MyFloatField.Text; //'1234.56'
  B := MyFloatField.DisplayText; //'$1,234.56', depends on your locale
  ShowMessage(A + #13 + B);
end;
```

El comportamiento de ambas propiedades puede ser personalizado escribiendo un manejador de eventos para `OnGetText`, dónde se puede escribir la lógica para convertir el valor del campo en una de ambas representaciones textuales. El parámetro booleano `DisplayText` indica si la cadena solicitada es para representar el valor en la interfaz de usuario o para edición.

De esta manera, podemos lograr que la representación en la interfaz de usuario para un campo entero con valor 1 sea 'uno', y su valor para edición sea 'one'

## `AsString`

Por otro lado, la propiedad AsString utiliza una conversión plana entre el tipo de dato base del campo y una cadena de caracteres. Cada descendiente de `TField` implementa el método virtual `GetAsString` que típicamente utiliza funciones de la RTL para realizar la conversión. Siguiendo con el ejemplo de TFloatField, esta clase llama a la función FloatToStr() para realizar la conversión.

## La respuesta

Dicho todo esto, la respuesta a la pregunta sería:

AsString retorna usualmente el mismo valor que retorna la propiedad Text, siempre que no haya un manejador de evento para OnGetText, pero la representación podría ser diferente si hubiese un manejador de evento o un descendiente no estándar de TField.

Con la información dada, no puede decirse cuál es más apropiado, ya que esto depende de cuál es el uso que se le dará al valor retornado. Si se está utilizando para mostrar valores en la Interfaz de usuario, como se muestra en los ejemplos de código proporcionados, mi consejo es que utilices la propiedad `DisplayText`.

Comment: guau creo que esta es muy buena respuesta

Answer (score 6):

`.AsString` devuelve el mismo "*string*" que la propiedad `.Text` si no existe ningún controlador de eventos "Event Handler", `OnGetText`, pero de existir uno puede darse el caso de ser diferente, o quizás un descendiente en `TField` que no sea el estándar podría ocasionar que fuera diferente.

Saludos y espero ayude.

P.D: Sobre si hay una razón para usar una u otra no sabría decirle con total certeza eso dependería del uso que tenga previsto para el valor de retorno.

Answer (score 1):

Acerca del siguiente fragmento de la pregunta:

> Normalmente, para un memo, utilizo:

```
aMemo.Lines.Assign(tblAcct.FieldByName('History'))
```

> Y esto trabaja bien también.

Esta última práctica utilizando el método `Assign` es **completamente inapropiada** y puede conducir a obtener errores difíciles de depurar. Con el método `Assign` se está asignando la misma dirección de memoria y en tal sentido si se llegara a liberar (free) la memoria del campo `History` (para el ejemplo), quedaría también sin valor (`nil`) el contenido (`Lines`) del memo.

Recomiendo:

```
aMemo.Lines.Text := tblAcct.FieldByName('History').Text;
```

Comment: Angel, bienvenido a StackOverflow en Español. Lo que dices en tu respuesta es totalmente incorrecto. Te invito a investigar sobre el funcionamiento de Assign, o bien a formular una pregunta sobre para darme ocasión de responderte sobre el tema. Un saludo.